# Is there any way to embed MongoDB charts in my kivy program using PyMongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, kivy, pymongo

I have been working on a tracker. It takes the date of each entry and the time elapsed on said date and feeds it to a MongoDB database. I made a line graph using the data in MongoDB Charts but I can't seem to find any documentation on how to embed it in Python.

Is there a way to do it?

(I'm not including code since there is nothing to reproduce. I just want to know if there is any function available to achieve this)

My output screen looks like this right now:
[image: output]

I want to add the chart in the blank space below but can't find a way to embed it. I tried AsyncImage but that doesn't work (understandably so, since AsyncImage has no provisions for chartId).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This video will teach you how to use mongodb with python using PyMongo
https://pypi.org/project/kivy-garden.graph/

and i think you can get the data as text not as graph and visualize the data in kivy using graph visualization in kivy garden using this module:
https://pypi.org/project/kivy-garden.graph/

you can try other way to use mongodb like installing the graph from the DB as an img and then use the image in kivy

Comment: ah ok thanks a lot. I'll try the garden graph thing because the database gets uploaded every now and then so installing the image every time will be too much processing